# Create custom marker in Google Maps for Flex

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, maps, google-maps-markers

I  have to create a marker with 3 triangles at 120 degrees with each other. The fill colour of the three triangles will be different (to be decided depending upon the value of some other variable).

Google Maps can accept DisplayObjects as markers. How do I go about creating one manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create `Sprite` and draw something on its `graphics`. See [Graphics](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Graphics.html) for help.

Comment: UIComponent can't live in Sprite, you don't need it here. Just draw your circle and supply that CustMarker to map to see what happens. And never forget endFill() when calling beginFill(); You don't even strictly need to create custom class for this, graphics is public field.

Comment: Never mind my previous comment. I got how to create a sprite, draw a circle, and display it on the map. Now I need to draw something like this: [link]http://imgur.com/sK619
(its ok, if gradients are not possible)

**Edit:** I am extremely sorry. I hadn't refreshed this page. So I didn't notice that you had replied to my original comment before deleting it. And you are right. All I hard to do was directly use addChild on the sprite.

Comment: I marked your reply as the solution, since you were right about the approach. I figured out how to draw the figure I wanted.